# conexion de base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

buenas estoy tratando de conectarme a una base de datos que se encuentra en un servidor linux de donde trato de obtener los datos que se usan en mi aplicación web y no he logrado hacerlo ni agregando la ip y el puerto, no se si sea la estructura.
si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería mucho.
Este es mi código:

```
<?php
  session_start();
 class Conectar {
    protected $dbh;
    protected function conexion(){
        try {

            $conectar = $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:myip=localhost:3306;dbname=produccion","root","");
           
             return $conectar;
            
        } catch (Exception $e) {

            print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();  
            
        }
 
         } //cierre de llave de la function conexion()

         public function set_names(){

            return $this->dbh->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
         }

         public function ruta(){

            return "http://localhost/prueba1/";
         }

          public static function convertir($string){

             $string = str_replace(
             array('01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'),
             array('ENERO', 'FEBRERO', 'MARZO', 'ABRIL', 'MAYO', 'JUNIO', 'JULIO', 'AGOSTO', 'SEPTIEMBRE', 'OCTUBRE', 'NOVIEMBRE', ' DICIEMBRE'),
             $string
            );        
            return $string;
          }
    }//cierre de llave conectar         
            
?>
```

Comment: Buenas, corrige el texto a formato código `{}` y explica mejor por que estas conectandote a una base de datos en otro pc.

Comment: 1) ¿Qué error te muestra? 2) ¿Has probado a conectarte a esa BD usando algún programa de consola?

Comment: La base de datos, admite conexiones remotas?

Comment: En lugar de `'mysql:myip=localhost:3306...'` deberías tener `'mysql:host=192.168.1.4;dbname=production;port=3306','root',''`. Si tienes dudas, consulta [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php)

Comment: muchas gracias tratare de esa forma

Comment: Si el código no está en el mismo servidor que la base de datos, asegúrate de habilitar las conexiones remotas, es un requisito indispensable para que funcione.